# Bash MacOS Sierra - format diff command output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, diff

I need to format output from diff command in bash on macOS Sierra. I get the output in a single line and I need to get each difference on a separate line with Added/Deleted in front of each line. E.g.

> uses-feature: name='hardware.camera' uses-feature: name='hardware.low.camera' < > uses-implied-feature: name='hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps' uses-implied-feature: name='hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps' <

So I need to format it to look something like this:

```
Deleted uses-feature: name='hardware.camera' 
Added uses-feature: name='hardware.low.camera' 
Deleted uses-implied-feature: name='hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps' 
Added uses-implied-feature: name='hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
```

Comment: I think you should use `diff -y file1 file2`.

Comment: This is how am doing it now: DIFF=$(diff -a  --suppress-common-lines -y -W 500 <(sort existing.txt) <(sort new.txt))
echo $DIFF. This causes the output as a single long line. I want $DIFF to have each difference on a separate line with Added/Deleted marked in the beginning of each line.

Comment: If instead you do `echo "$DIFF"` (with the double quotes), you should see that the output is on separate lines as expected.